# Trying to add only unique elements to array

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, concurrency, mutex

I'm trying to keep track of all the "workers" that I have in an array. `m` is a struct that has a string field uuid and so does `args`. I'm not sure what is wrong here but the code is adding the workers with the same uuid again and again (as and when the code is called).

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: This code might be called concurrently (but the code is mutex-locked so it doesn't really matter)

```
    var pollingWrkr *Wrkr
    pollingWrkr = nil
    for idx, w := range m.workers {
        if w.uuid == args.WorkerUUID {
            pollingWrkr = &m.workers[idx]
            break
        }
    }

    // add new worker
    if pollingWrkr == nil {
        pollingWrkr = new(Wrkr)
        m.workers = append(m.workers, *pollingWrkr) // add worker to list
        log.Printf("worker %v added\n", args.WorkerUUID)
    }
```

Comment: the presented code never assigns the uuid to the worker, so none of them have a uuid or do they?

Comment: note that, because you're storing non-pointers in the slice you need to assign the uuid in the second loop, to `pollingWrkr.uuid` before append, or to `m.workers[len(m.workers)-1].uuid` after append.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! Thanks a lot; can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mkropriva pointed out, the new Wrkr's uuid was never being assigned.

```
if pollingWrkr == nil {
        pollingWrkr = new(Wrkr)
        pollingWrkr.uuid = args.WorkerUUID // THIS HERE SOLVED IT!!!
        m.workers = append(m.workers, *pollingWrkr) // add worker to list
        log.Printf("worker %v added\n", args.WorkerUUID)
    }
```